# Deploying to Firebase is breaking the execution of a script that uses .click() method to expand on bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

I have a website in which we explain the features of our classes plans and some of the features are linked to from another website that's using Bootstrap accordion components to explain some of our activities, features, etc.

So, the script that was working and not anymore, is meant to open the accordion (using the `.click()`) that explains the feature clicked on the plans page. So it is working but as soon as I deploy again to Firebase (since I changed some HTML and CSS but nothing else) it stops working.

### Code

```
function expandByUrl() {

    let getHash = window.location.hash;
    console.log(getHash);

    let getTarget = getHash.slice(1);
    console.log(getTarget);

    let targetButton = document.getElementById(getTarget);
    console.log(targetButton);

    targetButton.click();
    console.log("clicked!");

}

window.onload(expandByUrl());
```

What I'm doing with this code is extracting the ID from the browser URL that the user clicked on the other website, and then simulating a client click with the `.click()` method on the targetID.

### Console Output

```
directLink.js:4 #explicandoCognostic

directLink.js:7 explicandoCognostic

directLink.js:10 <button id=​"explicandoCognostic" class=​"btn btn-link" type=​"button" data-toggle=​"collapse" data-target=​"#collapseOne" aria-expanded=​"false" aria-controls=​"collapseOne">​…​</button>​

directLink.js:13 clicked!
```

Any ideas on why it stops working when I deploy my new HTML / CSS?